# fopen / fread / fseek / fwrite / fclose not return on 10T storage

Tags: c++, linux, storage, fopen

We have a problem on fopen / fread / fseek / fwrite / fclose not return on 10T storage, I am not sure which function was stuck, in this case, we cannot get the errno, and the thread was stuck by one of these functioins.

We have 32 bit production working on 64 bit OS.

Do you have any suggestions on this issue?

function:

```
if(fullpath.empty())
    return ER_OK;

LOG("change mtime of:"<<fullpath);

FILE *fp=::fopen(fullpath.c_str(), "r+");
if(!fp)
{
    if(ENOENT == errno) return ER_OK;

    return errno;
}

uint8_t b=0;
int io_err=0;
int rlen=::fread(&b, 1, sizeof(b), fp);
if(rlen != sizeof(b))
{
    if(::feof(fp))
    {
        ::fclose(fp);
        fp=NULL;

        return ER_OK;
    }

    io_err=::ferror(fp);
    ::fclose(fp);
    fp=NULL;

    return io_err;
}

if(::fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, 0))
{
    io_err=errno;
    ::fclose(fp);
    fp=NULL;

    return io_err;
}

int wlen=::fwrite(&b, 1, sizeof(b), fp);
if(wlen != sizeof(b))
{
    if(::feof(fp))
    {
        ::fclose(fp);
        fp=NULL;

        return ER_OK;
    }

    io_err=::ferror(fp);
    ::fclose(fp);
    fp=NULL;

    return io_err;
}

::fclose(fp);
fp=NULL;

LOG("done");

return ER_OK;
```

Comment: Perhaps it's time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: What is 10T storage?

Comment: _and the thread was stuck by one of these functions_: maybe finding out in what function exactly the thread gets stuck may help. Other then that you may simply have stumbled upon a multi threading issue such as a deadlock.

Comment: Fyi, your last two arguments to `feek` are reversed. `SEEK_SET` should be the last argument; the relative position should be the second. Most systems `SEEK_SET` is zero, but you may as well play by the rules since someone went to the trouble of writing them.Just saying.

Comment: Given you said you're using a 32bit binary, and if 10T means something like 10 terrabytes, you might need to `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` before any includes, and use `fseeko()` instead of `fseek()`.